# Set Layout Parameters on click button by edit Text dynamically by selecting view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, parameters

What I am exactly trying to do is there are two Button views in a view group and there are two edit boxes to get the height and width and a button 3 to apply changes, when a view is selected we can provide height and width and then press button three to apply changes on the selected view button... I've used Layout Parameters, with one button it went perfectly fine, But I do not know how to tell button three that which view is selected to apply layout changes.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ll8.jpg)

Comment: Hello Rupesh. Please consider providing us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as what you have done so far to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the onClickListener to all the Views that you want to have resize.

```
button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnClickListener(someOnClickListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(someOnClickListener);
```

In `onClick` of this `someOnClickListener`, you have to get the ID of current View that was clicked, and save it in a variable.

```
int id_of_the_view_that_was_clicked = view.getId();
```

Above code to get the view Id will come in `OnClick()`.

After doing that, set `OnClickListener` for your button which when clicked you want the other `Views` to be resized.

In that, you can do like,

```
yourActivity.this.findViewById(id_of_the_view_that_was_clicked).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thank You so much it worked like a charm Sir... unable to give you vote ...might be due to I am new here on Stack Overflow..thanks again

Comment: how can I use same method for different button onclick i tried implements View.onclick (overrride method) might not working because of id_of_the_view_that_was_clicked is not global variable...heres my code [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12un2yByEFlZ2eG1PCHGfP1B-6vf47kWTBE2s6EyGtTA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'll check in a sec

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12un2yByEFlZ2eG1PCHGfP1B-6vf47kWTBE2s6EyGtTA/edit?usp=sharing thats the edited one. Check for syntax errors as it has autocorrected some of the keywords